# JavaScript "staggered checkerboard"

Tags: javascript

I had this question for a code test, and this is what I came up with:

```
    function pattern(){
        var str = ''

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 9){
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                    if (j == 0 || j == 3 || j == 6 || j == 9){
                        str += '1'      
                    } else {
                        str += '0'
                    }
                    if (j == 9){
                        str += '\n'
                    }
                }           
            }
            if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 7){
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                    if (j == 1 || j == 4 || j == 7){
                        str += '1'      
                    } else {
                        str += '0'
                    }
                    if (j == 9){
                        str += '\n'
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8){
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                    if (j == 2 || j == 5 || j == 8){
                        str += '1'
                    } else {
                        str += '0'
                    }
                    if (j == 9){
                        str += '\n'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(str)
    }
```

This is the output:

> 1001001001
>      0100100100
>      0010010010
>      1001001001
>      0100100100
>      0010010010
>      1001001001
>      0100100100
>      0010010010
>      1001001001

So it works, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to code this up.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: Working code improvement questions go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, it looks like things could be simplified using the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()).

Comment: What is expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does the same:

```
function pattern(){
    var str = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var iMod = i % 3;
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            if (j % 3 == iMod){
                str += '1'      
            } else {
                str += '0'
            }
        }
        str += '\n'
    }
    console.log(str)
}
```

Comment: It definitely does.  Thank you sir.

Comment: Cool! If it works for you, make sure to make an answer as the solution for other users.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I can think of.

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
  var str = "1001001001001001001";
  console.log(str.substring(str.length-10-i, str.length-i));
}
```